# Information about development HMI automotive

Tags: android

How can I design a car dashboard? I was told that there is a special version of Android to develop this operating system: can it be Android N?
Are there useful sites for developers? Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are thinking about Android Auto: 
https://www.android.com/auto/

Comment: Is not Android Auto just an app that invokes the Maps app, phone book, and media player app for audio tracks? I mean an operating system installed in the new cars

Comment: In the tablet on the right there is Android Auto. How do I make the screen behind the steering wheel? Source: first image http://fortune.com/2016/06/01/google-android-cars/

Comment: [Another article that shows what I'm saying](https://www.theverge.com/2016/5/18/11704960/google-qualcomm-maserati-future-of-android-cars)

Comment: This seems to be just a showcase/concept brought to you by Google and Maserati. To create the screen behind the steering wheel you will have to create the hardware.

Comment: Ok, I need HW, but for the SW speech of what do I need?

Comment: Can I make any tests with Andorid Studio? This is my main question.

Comment: What kind of tests are you thinking about. Of course you can make a screen with the GUI-components (gauges etc.) in Android Studio. I order to make the GUI-components respond to the actual "actions" from the car, you will have to need the required hardware such as an OBD2 reader etc. I think you should be more specific when asking.

Comment: I would like to start android studio, see two screens and every screen does something. Do you know what are the funzionality and limits of Android Automotive?